# What does Ctrl + Click do in IE9.0 when link have target='_blank'

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hyperlink, internet-explorer-9, gmail

When IE9.0 users visits my site from a link in their Gmail, they experience a strange problem - I notice that if they do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Mouse click</kbd> on the link all is working fine. So my question is:

In IE9.0, what is the difference between doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse click</kbd> or just <kbd>Mouse click</kbd> on a link with attribute `target='_blank'`?

Comment: **Nothing** and it's **not limited to IE** (well, shortcut to open a link in a new tab may be different in another browser).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but it cannot be true. 1: the new tab is not getting focus when doing ctrl+click and 2: as I said in my question, my page behave differently if you come to it from Gmail having done ctrl+click or normal click.

Comment: It doesn't get the focus just because CTRL-click behavior overrides _blank (so it'll keep current tab selected) but it's absolutely browser dependant. HOW your app behaves differently?

Comment: My file upload works well when coming from Gmail after doing CTRL+click, when doing normal click it gives "Access Denied". This only happens when user comes from Gmail and only in IE9.0 - I swear it is true (I have not been smoking).